# Find match values from other CSV file then append back matching values as new columns in a csv file

Tags: bash, shell, csv

I have 2 CSV file, which are contain more than 500 lines

1 contain product info

```
ID, names, url, color, size
p01, abc, uploads/abc.jpg, red, M
P02, abz, uploads/abz.jpg, yellow, S
p03, xyz, uploads/xyz.jpg, green, L
p04, qwe, uploads/qwe.jpg, blue, XL
```

the other contain the location of the image relate to that product, one product have many imgs.

```
ID, product_id, url
01, p01, uploads/item/asa.jpg
02, p01, uploads/item/aza.jpg
03, p01, uploads/item/dna.jpg
04, p01, uploads/item/adn.jpg
05, p02, uploads/item/bka.jpg
06, p02, uploads/item/bda.jpg
07, p04, uploads/item/cde.jpg
```

And a result like this

```
ID, names, url, color, size, thumb1, thumb2, thumb3, thumb4, ....
p01, abc, uploads/abc.jpg, red, M, uploads/item/asa.jpg, uploads/item/aza.jpg, uploads/item/dna.jpg, uploads/item/adn.jpg
P02, abz, uploads/abz.jpg, yellow, S, uploads/item/bka.jpg, uploads/item/bda.jpg
p03, xyz, uploads/xyz.jpg, green, L, 
p04, qwe, uploads/qwe.jpg, blue, XL, uploads/item/cde.jpg
```

So what utilities can I do in terminal?

Comment: Whats with the capital P in the second file ?

Comment: hi, it is the product id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "}
     NR==1{print "ID, names, url, color, size, thumbnails"; next}
     FNR==NR{$2=tolower($2); a[$2] = (a[$2]?a[$2] ", " $3:$3); next}
     FNR>1{print $0, a[tolower($1)]}' file2 file1
```

**Output:**

```
ID, names, url, color, size, thumbnails
p01, abc, uploads/abc.jpg, red, M, uploads/item/asa.jpg, uploads/item/aza.jpg, uploads/item/dna.jpg, uploads/item/adn.jpg
P02, abz, uploads/abz.jpg, yellow, S, uploads/item/bka.jpg, uploads/item/bda.jpg
p03, xyz, uploads/xyz.jpg, green, L,
p04, qwe, uploads/qwe.jpg, blue, XL, uploads/item/cde.jpg
```

Comment: Yeah, it work perfectly after I change OFS=", " to this OFS="," (remove space). Thank you anubhava, your awk is rock!